# Cocos2d-x v3.0rc1 PhysicsBody Contact Issue

Tags: android, c++, ios, cocos2d-x

Having an issue where physics body collisions/contacts aren't working the way I anticipate. I may be misinterpreting how they're supposed to work. My understanding is that if physicsBodyA has a category bitmask of 0x1, and physicsBodyB has a contact test bitmask of 0x1, contact tests should evaluate to true and I should be getting a callback from the event dispatcher.

This isn't working, however. The only way that I get a contact evaluating to true is of I also set physicsBodyA's contact bitmask to match the category bitmask of physicsBodyB. Basically, the category and contact test bitmasks must mirror one another. In practice it looks something like this:

```
bool TestLayer::init() {

    // Call super init
    if (!Layer::init()) {
        return false;
    }

    // Get screen size
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();

    // Bitmasks
    int BITMASK_BOUNDARY = 0x1 << 0;
    int BITMASK_HERO = 0x1 << 1;

    // Boundary node
    Node *boundaryNode = Node::create();
    boundaryNode->setAnchorPoint(Point(0.5, 0.5));
    boundaryNode->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width/2.0, visibleSize.height/2.0));

    // Physics body for boundary node
    PhysicsBody *boundaryBody = PhysicsBody::createEdgeBox(visibleSize);
    boundaryBody->setCategoryBitmask(BITMASK_BOUNDARY);
    boundaryBody->setContactTestBitmask(BITMASK_HERO);
    boundaryBody->setDynamic(false);

    // Set boundary body and add to scene
    boundaryNode->setPhysicsBody(boundaryBody);
    this->addChild(boundaryNode);

    // Hero node
    Sprite *hero = Sprite::create("hero_ship.png");
    hero->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width/2.0, visibleSize.height - 30.0));

    // Physics body for hero node
    PhysicsBody *heroBody = PhysicsBody::createBox(hero->getContentSize());
    heroBody->setCategoryBitmask(BITMASK_HERO);

    // Set hero body and add to scene
    hero->setPhysicsBody(heroBody);
    this->addChild(hero);

    /*
     * NOTICE: If I don't set the contact test bitmask on my hero
     * body, the event listener onContactBegin callback will not
     * be called.
     */

    heroBody->setContactTestBitmask(BITMASK_BOUNDARY);

    // Create an event listener
    EventListenerPhysicsContact *listener = EventListenerPhysicsContact::create();

    // Use lambda for listener callback
    listener->onContactBegin = [](PhysicsContact &contact) {
        CCLOG("Physics contact began.");
        return true;
    };

    // Register listener with event dispatcher
    this->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);

    // Everything worked out on init, return true
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Box2D Manual:

***-------- Quoted***

> Collision filtering allows you to prevent collision between fixtures.
>   For example, say you make a character that rides a bicycle. You want
>   the bicycle to collide with the terrain and the character to collide
>   with the terrain, but you don't want the character to collide with the
>   bicycle (because they must overlap). Box2D supports such collision
>   filtering using categories and groups. Box2D supports 16 collision
>   categories. For each fixture you can specify which category it belongs
>   to. You also specify what other categories this fixture can collide
>   with. For example, you could specify in a multiplayer game that all
>   players don't collide with each other and monsters don't collide with
>   each other, but players and monsters should collide. This is done with
>   masking bits. For example:

```
playerFixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = 0x0002; 
monsterFixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = 0x0004; 
playerFixtureDef.filter.maskBits = 0x0004; 
monsterFixtureDef.filter.maskBits = 0x0002;
```

> Here is the rule for a collision to occur:

```
uint16 catA = fixtureA.filter.categoryBits; 
uint16 maskA = fixtureA.filter.maskBits; 
uint16 catB = fixtureB.filter.categoryBits; 
uint16 maskB = fixtureB.filter.maskBits;
if ((catA & maskB) != 0 && (catB & maskA) != 0) 
{
  // fixtures can collide
}
```

***-------- End of Quote***

So the bottom line is that if you want two things to react the same way with each other in terms of collisions, they both must have the same category and mask bits.

For some more a (very good) in-depth discussion of this, go ahead and [look at this site](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering) (no, it is not mine).

For some other interesting Box2D stuff, [look here](http://www.nlideas.com) (this one is mine).

Comment: Note that Cocos2d-x v3 doesn't use Box2d, but Chipmunk, and it's not so obvious how the 2 bitmasks used by Box2d relate to the 3 bitmasks used in Cocos2d-x...